# How to count Forms in project using C#

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I am using below code to get form count in C# using Assembly

```
int _packCounter = 0;
Assembly assemblies = Assembly.Load("MyProjectName");
Form f = null;
Type[] types = assemblies.GetTypes();
foreach (Type t in types)
{
    if (t.IsPublic && t.BaseType == typeof(Form))
    {
        f = (Form)assemblies.CreateInstance(t.FullName);
        if (f.Tag.ToString().ToUpper() != "NO")
        {
            _packCounter++;   
        }
    }

    else if (t.IsPublic && t.BaseType == typeof(MetroForm))
    {
        f = (MetroForm)assemblies.CreateInstance(t.FullName);
        if (f.Tag.ToString().ToUpper() != "NO")
        {
            _packCounter++;                               
        }
    }
}
```

it working fine, but its using loop,

**My question is : how its done without any loop**

**Edit :**

As I was told Its Working but its by using Loop, this code will be use again and again my application as per my requirement, so some time I will face performance issues. So I want to avoid loop

Comment: What exactly are you counting? *"it working fine, but its using loop"* - what is the problem with loop?

Comment: You aren't counting forms. You are looking for specific types and their children. Indeed, what's wrong with the loop? Too slow? Doesn't get what you expect? Slow because of inefficient coding, like usint `ToString().ToUpper()` instead of `String.Equals()` with a case-insensitive option?

Comment: Or is it the fact that you *instantiate* each form in order to search for a specific property value? Again, that's not a problem with the loop. Use an *attribute* if you want to attach information to a class, just as .NET does with `Serializable`, `DisplayColumn` etc. You can retrieve a type's attributes with `Type.GetAttributes` or even check for a *specific* attribute type

Comment: The problem isn't the loop, it's the use of the `Tag` property.  What are you trying to do with this code? Can't you use an *existing* attribute, like those found in DataAnnotations ? Perhaps what you are trying to do is already implemented by .NET ?

Comment: Anyway, if you wanted to find types with a specific attribute, eg `NoAttribute` you could use [GetCustomAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d(v=vs.110).aspx) and  write `myType.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NoAttribute,false))`.

Comment: Furthermore, isn't `MetroForm` derived from Form? You could use `Type.IsSubclassOf()` or `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` to find all types derived from Form

Comment: Your edit mentions performance issues. It's not the *loop* that causes performance issues, it's the use of the instance property `Tag`. No matter how quickly you retrieve all form-derived classes, creating an instance for each one is going to be **slow** and eat up memory. `gain and again in my application` why is this an issue? Calculate this once and save the results

Comment: This sounds more and more like a case of [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about the actual problem X, you ask about your attempted solution Y. What is the *actual* problem? Are you trying to implement a plugin architecture perhaps? One where forms are loaded dynamically from plugin assemblies unless they are marked in a special way?

Comment: There is built-in support for such things in .NET through [MEF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/mef/index), the more appropriate [System.Addin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/add-ins/), various dependency injection containers that automatically register types in assemblies. Again, all these use *attributes*, not instance properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use linq for easy way of querying instead of checking each in forloop

```
 int _packCounter = 0;
 Assembly assemblies = Assembly.Load("MyProjectName");
 Type[] types = assemblies.GetTypes();
 _packCounter = types.Where(x => (x.IsPublic && x.BaseType == typeof(Form)) || (x.IsPublic && x.BaseType == typeof(MetroForm))).Count();
```

Comment: The OP's query is more complex than this.

Comment: and what about Form.Tag = "No", Its returning all form count